# Can anyone identify what the name of this outfit?

Tags: fallout-4

I've looking for this armor for a long time, but i can't find a name, please tell me.
[image]

Comment: This looks like the thumbnail of some YouTube video. Where did you get it from? I believe there's a good chance this armor is from a mod.

Comment: If you're not on PS4 and want some cool armour, just use mods. There are some awesome mods out there for Fallout 4. I played through to get trophies then made my own mods. Btw, that video was made in 2016 and he's talking about balistic weave from the Railroad and Perk setup and stuff.

Answer (score 4):

The armor does not appear to exist within Fallout 4, and was likely fan-made for the sake of the image. Per Nolonar's comment and Google Reverse Image Searching, the screenshot appears to be taking from [this](https://youtu.be/ww0elqpZfXo) Youtube video.

Various comments on the video state that the is not within the game

> **User**: I wish the armor in the thumb nail was actually in the game

and

> **User**: what is the armor hes wearing in the thumb nail?
>
> **Response**: it's not actually armor